# Hashing of 2D points considering little error

Tags: c#, hash, 2d, point, difference

I would like to ask, if there is any good way to hash 2D points considering a little error.
I am creating some points, but the coordinates are counted with division and other arithmetic operations, so results could be little bit different for the same points (for example sometimes I get coordinate 4.0000001 and sometimes 4.0000000).

I know that points are same if their difference is less than 0.1 in both coordinates. But when I hash 4.0000001 and 4.0000000 with .GetHashCode() on Point in C# a get different hashes (which is obvious). Is there any way to consider hashing which is able to omit these little errors and when two points are the same (they dont differ too much) they have also same hash?

Comment: "sometimes I get coordinate 4.0000001 and sometimes 4.0000000" Round the coordinates after they are calculated?

Comment: I though that rounding of doubles can lead to similar weird behaviour, because the numbers are stored as binary numbers so rounding to decimal point can also produce these errors or am I wrong?